# Express next() is triggering next route which is parameterised after next() from current route is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, express-router

I have this route, `/test` which I called but somehow it is triggering `/:async` route as well when next() is called in `/test` route's finally?

```
router.post('/test/:value?'async (req, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {|
   try{
     //code
   }catch(err){
     //log error
   }finally{
     next();
   }
})

router.post('/:id?'async (req, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
   try{
     //code
   }catch(err){
     //log error
   }finally{
     next();
   }
})
```

I have this `finalResponseHandler` middleware in server.ts file which is supposed to be called on next().

```
app.use(finalResponseHandler);
```

If I remove `/:id?` route `finalResponseHandler` middleware is called perfectly.
Why is this /:id route is getting called instead of finalResponseHandler middleware?
How do I correct this to not call `/:id` route when calling '/test' route.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for that it's because express see this as a middleware function with a `/test/:value?` path. and the same for the second route, i suggest you remove `next()` from `/test/....`

Comment: If I remove `next()` how would I call middleware `finalResponseHandler`?

Comment: nex() calls the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle so you either leave next() but then you have to add the middleware underneath  /test or if you want the middleware called before `/:id` you can add the middleware to the route like this `router.post('/:id?', finalResponseHandler,async (req, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction)`

Comment: requirement is finalResponseHandler should be called after processing the route, not before.

Comment: if you want the middleware to be route agnostic, put it in your main index/app.js and it will be always called for any request response cycle

Comment: Yes it is in app,js, `app.use(finalResponseHandler)`;

Comment: so you want it to be called after /test and after /:id ? is that correct?

Comment: I want middleware to be called after /test/ but do not want to trigger /:id route in any way.

Comment: then you have to require and add the middleware underneath /test or add it to the route right after you send the response